# WPF: Trigger button Press from thread other than UI thread

Tags: c#, wpf, multithreading

I have a callback function from which I want to trigger a button press.
I have tried the UIAutomation Interface that I found on another question:

```
ButtonAutomationPeer peer = new ButtonAutomationPeer(button_Read);
IInvokeProvider invokeProv = peer.GetPattern(PatternInterface.Invoke) as IInvokeProvider;
invokeProv.Invoke();
```

But I get an exception

> The calling thread cannot access this object because a different thread owns it.

How can I trigger button from another thread?
Is there a way to "emit" an event that the UI Thread then catches?

Comment: Have you tried using Dispatcher class?

Comment: Thanks for the hint! I'm new to c# and wpf, so I didn't know about it. Works now: `Application.Current.Dispatcher.Invoke(new Action(() => { /* ButtonAutomationPeer peer... */ }));`

Comment: Basically in WPF your UI thread is a main thread of your application, that owns all UI controls. You don't have to use Dispatcher if you are inside UI thread, but it won't let you call any UI actions from any other thread, just like you have experienced.

Comment: You can use either `Dispatcher` or create a `SynchronizationContext` and some `ThreadSynchronization` class that will be responsible for calling anything you want on the UI Thread.